# Exporting an aspx panel to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am trying to export the contents in an aspx web panel to pdf. The aspx panel contains table, text, chart, and most importantly, dynamic google maps. Can anyone give me some idea about how to do that?

I have tried this by first converting the whole web page to bitmap image, then converting the bitmap into pdf using iTextSharp. This approach works to some extent. However, I do not want everything in the aspx page in the pdf, just the contents in a particular aspx panel.

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: You will need to create another aspx page containing just the panel and render that to PDF. You can either load it in a new tab/window and prompt the user or you can do it on the server and send it back on the response stream as an attachment, which will prompt the user to save a file.

Answer (score 0):

Render the contents of the `Panel` control to an `HtmlTextWriter` and then write to the PDF as usual, like this:

```
protected void YourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=YourPane.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    // Call your panel by ID to render the contents to HTML
    YourPanel.RenderControl(hw);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);

    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

    pdfDoc.Open();

    htmlparser.Parse(sr);

    pdfDoc.Close();

    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```